# How to get the nearest date to a record date in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query

I have the following data structure:

**Table A**:

```
ID  |  RequestNumber  |  Date
----+-----------------+-----------
 1  |      1          |2017/09/27
 2  |      1          |2018/06/02
```

**Table B**:

```
RequestNumber  |  Serial  |  Date
---------------+----------+----------
     1         |    1     |2017/09/27
     1         |    2     |2017/09/27
     1         |    6     |2018/06/03
     1         |    7     |2018/06/03
     1         |    8     |2018/06/03
```

As we can see the nearest date to the first row of `Table A` is 2017/09/27  in the `Table B` and the nearest date to the second row is 2018/06/03 in the `Table B`

So...

I need a query to have each row from `Table A` with all rows from `Table B` that is the nearest to the record from `Table A` (it means 2 records should be returned the first record and 3 records should be returned for the second record)

The expected result would be:

```
ID  |  RequestNumber  |  Serial  |  Date
----+-----------------+----------+------------
 1  |      1          |    1     | 2017/09/27
 1  |      1          |    2     | 2017/09/27
 2  |      1          |    6     | 2018/06/03
 2  |      1          |    7     | 2018/06/03
 2  |      1          |    8     | 2018/06/03
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you are defining nearest? is it if the date falls between the last 2 or next 2 days or is there any logic for that?

Answer (score 2):

Inner sub-query returns the nearest date.

```
SELECT
    ta.ID,
    ta.RequestNumber,
    tb.Serial,
    tb.dt
FROM
    ta
JOIN
    tb
    ON tb.RequestNumber = ta.RequestNumber
    AND tb.dt = (SELECT TOP 1 
                     dt
                 FROM
                     tb
                 WHERE
                     RequestNumber = ta.RequestNumber
                     AND dt >= ta.dt 
                 ORDER BY
                     RequestNumber,
                     dt ASC);
```

Or you cans use a DENSE_RANK to flag rows by RequestNumber + Date and get the rank = 1.

```
SELECT
    ta.ID,
    ta.RequestNumber,
    tb.Serial,
    tb.dt
FROM   
    ta
CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT RequestNumber, Serial, dt,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestNumber 
                                 ORDER BY RequestNumber, dt) rn
             FROM tb
             WHERE tb.RequestNumber = ta.RequestNumber
                   AND tb.dt >= ta.dt
            ) tb
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Both queries return the same result:

```
ID | RequestNumber | Serial | dt                 
-: | ------------: | -----: | :------------------
 1 |             1 |      1 | 27/09/2017 00:00:00
 1 |             1 |      2 | 27/09/2017 00:00:00
 2 |             1 |      6 | 03/06/2018 00:00:00
 2 |             1 |      7 | 03/06/2018 00:00:00
 2 |             1 |      8 | 03/06/2018 00:00:00
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c6b6949cc1cb2e1c1a85fd0d7d0a11d0)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
declare @tableA table(ID int,RequestNumber int,  Dates date)
insert into @tableA VALUES
(1,1,'2017/09/27')
,(2 ,1,'2018/06/02')

 --select * from @tableA

declare @tableB table(RequestNumber int,Serial int, Dates date)
insert into @tableB VALUES
 (1 ,1 ,'2017/09/27')
,(1 ,2 ,'2017/09/27')
,(1 ,6 ,'2018/06/03')
,(1 ,7 ,'2018/06/03')
,(1 ,8 ,'2018/06/03')

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT A.*
        ,b.Dates AS DateA
    FROM @tableA A
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 Dates
        FROM @tableB B
        WHERE B.Dates >= a.Dates
        ORDER BY b.Dates
        ) B
    )
SELECT c.id
    ,b.RequestNumber
    ,b.Serial
    ,b.Dates
FROM @tableB B
LEFT JOIN CTE C ON b.Dates = c.DateA
```